Best model for data with categorical variables lmer
I have some data composed of a continuous dependent variable in minutes and several categorical independent variables. I fitted this model but was advised on Stack Overflow that my model might not be well constructed when I was asking about problems fitting the predict() function (my other question).
This is the model:
model <- lmer(minutes_after_sunrise ~ forest * forest_strata * habitat +
                                      (1 | forest_strata), data = data)

minutes_after_sunrise is a given minute when a species was detected to data in minutes (I also have negatives, minutes before sunrise, but didn't include them in this model), the forest is sites A and B, forest strata is the vertical section of the forest (ground to canopy in total 6 layers for both A and B) and habitat (two categories) which is different habitats within forests A and B also having strata so everything is very nested. I thought to include strata as a fixed effect, but being sincerely honest I don't have a lot of experience with these models so it well could be all wrong. Could someone advise me on what would be the best fit?
What I want to know is if minutes after sunrise vary between forests A and B and how the other elements such as strata and habitat also might play their part in this. I am finding it difficult to work on this model due to only having categorical data.
Example of my data, I have around 78.000 rows like these.


Hi, it would be helpful if you could share a small toy dataset with the same data structure as your actual data, now it's a bit difficult to understand the data structure, but having forest_strata as both fixed effect and random effect grouping variable is at least incorrect. You can only have it as one of those, not both.

But with the given information, putting strata in as fixed effect (removing the random effect) and using an otherwise identical single-level (lm) model might work. However sounds like your outcome may be a count, in which case regular linear model may not be the best.

@Sointu I've added some examples of my data, I have about 78.000 rows like those. Very many thanks!!

The example is good, but it's best to include such information in text format (e.g. cut-and-paste text into a code block delimited with triple-backquotes) rather than as an image/screenshot ...

As far as I can tell the main issue here is not the nature of your predictor (independent) variables, but that (as suggested in comments here and on Stack Overflow) that you don't appear to have any predictors that would be sensibly treated as a random effect — therefore you should be using a plain old (generalized?) linear model (lm() or glm() in R).

nothing in what you've told us suggests that you need to use a mixed model. All of the categorical variables are non-exchangeable (i.e. different levels have specific meanings, you couldn't (for example) change the labels of the forest strata and have an equivalent data set), with the possible exception of forest A and B, and there you don't have enough levels to practically treat the variable as a random effect. The fact that your variables are crossed (you have measured all strata in both forests) or nested (if you had different strata in each forest) doesn't really make a difference.
including forest_strata both as a fixed effect and as a random effect grouping variable will definitely mess you up
how you treat your response variable (lm() vs glm(), family for GLM) isn't completely obvious (but also might not make a very big difference):

lm(minutes_after_sunrise ~ ...) might be OK, especially if the values of minutes_after_sunrise are reasonably large/far from zero
positive variables (those that can't be negative or zero, by definition) are often modeled with a log-Normal (i.e., use lm(log(minutes_after_sunrise) ~ ...) or a log-link Gamma (glm(minutes_after_sunrise ~ ..., family = Gamma(link="log"))), but this might not be as appropriate if have a lot of responses near zero (i.e. if, within a habitat/forest/stratum combination the distribution looks like a Normal distribution that is truncated at zero)



I would suggest using lm() with either the raw or the logged values as your response, then run performance::check_model() to see diagnostics. If they look OK (you should worry most about the 'homogeneity of variance' panel).
How much data do you have?  The full model you specified (with the random effect dropped) will fit 262 = 24 parameters. A standard rule of thumb would say you should have about 24*10 = 240 data points if you want to fit this model reliably. If you have fewer you might want to revert to an additive model forest + forest_strata + habitat (8 parameters) or include only some of the interactions.

Hi, I've added some details about the data. Minutes from sunrise can be all the way from 1 to 1000 because is the moment a species is detected after sunrise. The negative in the column minutes after sunrise are those detected before sunrise (similar happens with minutes after sunset). I hope that adds some clarity to it!!

Hi @Benbolker thanks for that. However, is my data not nested? if yes would this not mean it needs to be covered and used a mixed model? I am feeling more confused than I was before, please help    :(

@CrazyBirdLady it is (in the sense that observations are clustered within strata), but you don't always have to use a mixed model to handle nested data. One alternative way is to model the clustering/nesting variable as a fixed effect, which is what professor Bolker suggests here.

Also, there are two ways of using "nested" in the LMM context. You seem to be using it to refer simply to the fact that you have several observations per stratum (and per habitat and forest). But another way of using "nested", used in the answer above is when you have 2 or more possible random effect grouping variables and you are considering whether one of them is nested within the other or not. Your possible random effects (strata, habitat and forest) are not nested within each other. If you chose to use 2 or 3 of them as random effects, they would be crossed random effects, not nested.

Hello @Sointu Now I understand a bit better, sorry I was not getting it. Do you recommend any guide I could use to see and follow for the most appropriate approach? I think this analysis is getting out of my hands and it is getting a lot more complicated than I thought it would be, for example never heart of crossed random effects. very many thanks for your time :)

No worries, these are complicated issues :) So, if you choose to use a single-level model (lm instead of lmer) as suggested, your model will be just a regular regression model with 3 categorical predictors. This is equivalent to a 3-way ANOVA. You can find tons of resources on these analyses online. To read about using a categorical variable (such as your forest_strata) as a fixed predictor vs. random effects, see for instance Ben Bolker's answer here

But basically, you can leave mixed models and data nesting (clustering) aside for now. Try what professor Bolker suggested: model<-lm(minutes_after_sunrise ~ forest * forest_strata * habitat, data=data). Then, there is a completely separate issue of possibly needing to log transform your response variable if model diagnostics of that first model look bad.
